# Qual é o genêro dos pronomes isto, isso e aquilo?

Tags: gramática

Segundo algumas fontes, estes pronomes são invariáveis quanto a gênero. Mas, são corretas frases como "Isto é bonita."?

Answer (score 3):

Não, não é correto dizer "isto é bonita". *Isto* (tal como *isso* e *aquilo*) não têm flexões (em género ou número) e concordam sempre com o masculino. Portanto:

> Esta coisa é bonita.
>   Isto é bonito.

Claro que isto não impede que se construam frases copulativas com *ser* com um sintagma nominal no feminino/plural:

> Estas coisas são dificuldades sérias.
>   Isto são dificuldades sérias.

Comment: Mas então deveria poder de «esta coisa é dificuldade séria» tirar «isto é dificuldade séria», e de seguida também de «esta coisa é bonita» tirar «isto é bonita»... ou não? Eu sinto fortemente que não, mas não consigo encontrar o racional para o justificar.

Comment: @ANeves, e de "ele é boa pessoa" tiras "ele é boa"!